# Rotating an NSImageCell

Tags: objective-c, nsmatrix, applescript-objc, nsimagecell

I'm working on a project where I have a large `NSMatrix` of `NSImageCells`. I need to rotate specific individual `Images` in their cells (or even just rotate the cells themselves since it will look the same way). Every cell and image is a 40x40 square, so there shouldn't have to be any resizing since I'll be sticking to 90 degree increments. The problem is that because I'm using `NSImageCells` instead of `NSImageViews`, I can't use `setFrameCenterRotation:` to easily rotate the images. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone still looking for a way to do this, since I'm writing this in ASOC, I ended up using this code:

```
on rotateImage_byAngle_(startingImage, angle)
    set rotated to current application's NSImage's alloc()'s initWithSize_({startingImage's |size|()'s height(), startingImage's |size|()'s |width|()})
    rotated's lockFocus()
    set transform to current application's NSAffineTransform's transform()
    transform's translateXBy_yBy_((rotated's |size|()'s |width|()) / 2, (rotated's |size|()'s height()) / 2)
    transform's rotateByDegrees_(angle)
    transform's translateXBy_yBy_(-(rotated's |size|()'s height()) / 2, -(rotated's |size|()'s |width|()) / 2)
    transform's concat()
    startingImage's drawAtPoint_fromRect_operation_fraction_({0, 0}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, current application's NSCompositeCopy, 1)
    rotated's unlockFocus()
    return rotated
end rotateImage_byAngle_
```